# Erro bindValue - conexão php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou fazendo um sistema de login usando php e mysql. Porém estou tendo um erro que não consigo solucionar.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue()

Alguém poderia me ajudar ? segue abaixo meu código para verem se possui algum erro.

```php
<?php
Class valida
{
    private $pdo;
    public $msgErro = "";

    public function conectar($nome, $host, $usuario, $senha)
    {
        session_start();
        global $pdo;
        global $msgErro;
        try{
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$nome.";host=".$host,$usuario,$senha);
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            $msgErro = $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
    public function logar($email, $senha)
    {
        global $pdo;
        global $msgErro;
        //verificar se o email e senha estão cadastrados
        $sql->bindValue(":e",$email);
        $sql->bindValue(":s",md5($senha));
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_enf from enfermeiro WHERE email = :e AND senha = :s");
        $sql->execute();
        if($sql->rowCount()>0)
        {
            //entrar no sistema (sessao)
            $dado = $sql->fetch();
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id_enf'] = $dado['id_enf'];
            return true; //logado com sucesso
        }
        else
        {
            return false; //nao foi possivel logar
        }
    }

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando chamar o `bindValue` na variável `$sql`, antes mesmo dela ser iniciada, veja:

```
<?php

    public function logar($email, $senha)
    {
        global $pdo;
        global $msgErro;
        //verificar se o email e senha estão cadastrados
        $sql->bindValue(":e",$email); // essa variável não existe ainda, ela é iniciada duas linhas depois
        $sql->bindValue(":s",md5($senha));
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_enf from enfermeiro WHERE email = :e AND senha = :s");
        $sql->execute();
    }


?>
```

O correto seria:

```
<?php

    public function logar($email, $senha)
    {
        global $pdo;
        global $msgErro;
        //verificar se o email e senha estão cadastrados
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_enf from enfermeiro WHERE email = :e AND senha = :s");
        $sql->bindValue(":e",$email);
        $sql->bindValue(":s",md5($senha));
        $sql->execute();
    }


?>
```